# Auto-selecting Record Type with Flow

Tags: record-type, flow

I want to ask the users several questions using Flow screen when they begin creating a record in order to determine which Record Type should be used. I would do this by using a button which calls a VF page with an embedded Flow and automatically populating the RecordTypeID according to their answers.

However, if I have multiple Record Types I will be prompted to manually choose a Record Type before the Flow screens begin after pressing the New button. How can I bypass the Record Type selection step to go directly to the Flow screen and then populate the Record Type field through the Flow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the standard new button with your visualforce page, and check the 'skip record type selection page' checkbox.

This will bypass the record type selection and take you to the flow.

[image: sample override new contact button]

Here is some info on overriding the standard button
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_customize_override.htm

Comment: Yes, I am already using that method. That method doesn't bypass the Record Type selection prompting. The user is still forced to select a Record Type before the Flow starts.

Comment: I would log a case w/ support.  I have a contact create flow and if the checkbox is checked, it skips record type selection.  If the checkbox is unchecked, the record type selection screen is displayed.  I have tested this multiple times, it works properly.

Comment: Well, that's good to know - thank you. What exactly are the steps for your flow ? I'd like to know to make sure you're not using a flow element which may be superseding the record type selection screen. Right now I'm doing it for Leads (I will be doing it for customi objects too). So I've customized the New button to open a VF page with one line (flow:interview name ="Create Leads"). The my Flow is simply 3 Screen elements asking questions and then a Record Create element. Are you doing anything different than that ?

Comment: My flow is just a single input screen to capture basic info - first name, last name, address, etc, and then some logic that tries to match on existing records via email, ensure some fields are populated, etc.  At its core it is a screen + a record create (account) + a record create (contact).

Comment: So how are you initiating your Flow ? Are you doing it with a New button which is aimed at a VF page with an interview line such as I am ? Also, which checkbox are you referring to which allows you to skip the record type when clicked ? Thank you.

Comment: Overriding new button, points at vf page w interview, as in the documentation.  See the screen shot in my original answer, the checkbox is there w label of 'skip record type selection pagr'

Comment: oh that's awesome. I didn't even notice that when you first put that screen shot up there. Thanks so much @gorav !